# Why do people dislike something?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Suppose a person sees a guy wearung red Tshirt and a pink trouser. At a first glance he disliked that combination of outfit, while another person beside him liked the combination. So why did this difference in perception of colour emerged even though they were looking at the same thing at the same condition? Is it because of their differences in upbringing? Or is it due to violation of uniformity of one's perception (I mean a person is more familiar with a combination of red and blue but when he saw the red-pink combo which is completely unfamiliar to him, he just could not take it because of asymmetry)?

Again someone likes to have meat and he eats it quite rarely. But he dislikes milk. Even he drinks milk everyday or rarely, he dislikes it. On the other hand even of he eats meat everyday he does not dislike that as he does dislike milk. Why does that happen? Is it something related to composition of milk and meat which involves chemistry to understand or is it completely a psychological topic?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Likes and dislikes are very much personal experiences and the reasons can be vastly different between each person. I may stand corrected, but the reasons for the dislikes you mention may lead more toward opinions rather than strong facts which determine those dislikes in all people, which is what we strive for in this site. As this is a scientific stack, we seek facts rather than opinions.

Comment: Have you looked anywhere online such as [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/)? What have you found? Is there anything you haven't quite understood?

Comment: I didm't look for answer to this question in Google scholar but did search in in Google. I did not get the answer I was looking for that is why asked here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the main theories that account for why some people like X and others not?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10410/7001)